# Should I move all the code inside onStartCommand() instead of onCreate()?

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-notifications

From what I understand the `onCreate()` method is only called only once (when the Service is instantiated), that would be the first time I execute `startService(intent)`, so it basically works like a constructor.
Instead the `onStartCommand()` is called every time I execute `startService(intent)`.

This is MyService.java code:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
      
        this.builder = builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
        .setContentTitle("My notification")
        .setContentText("Hello World!")
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
        // Set the intent that will fire when the user taps the notification
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(true);
        
        this.notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        // notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
        Notification notification = builder.build();
        this.notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        Thread thread = new MyThread(handler);
        thread.start();

        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification); //TODO right after notificationManager.notify or at the end of the method? 
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        if(intent != null)
            this.test = intent.getStringExtra("test");

        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action != null) {
            if (action.equals("Stop")) {
                stopForeground(true);
                stopSelf();
                return START_NOT_STICKY;
            }
        }
        //return START_STICKY;
        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }
```

I basically do all the work inside `onCreate()` and use `onStartCommand()` only to get a String extra and stop the service.
My MainActivity does simply start and stop of the service.
I have also tried moving all the code inside onStartCommand but honestly I didn't see any changes.

My questions are:

1. Should I move all the code inside the `onStartCommand()` method?
2. Is it good practice to build the notification at the beginning/end of the method or doesn't matter at all?
3. Should I call startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification) right after notificationManager.notify or at the end of the method?

Comment: You can just stop a service with stopService(intent), no need to start the service just to stop it

Comment: @tyczj I've seen other people preferring this approach maybe because of the stopForeground(). If I use stopService I should call stopForeground() in the onDestroy() method?